# Counting unique values based on partial text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got many items in boxes on a pallet. I would like to know how I can count the unique number of boxes in a pallet.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item | Pallet-box ID |  | Pallet No. | No. of boxes |
| 2 | abc | P01-B01 |  | P01 | ***5*** |
| 3 | def | P01-B01 |  | P02 | ***2*** |
| 4 | ghi | P01-B02 |  |  |  |
| 5 | jkl | P01-B02 |  |  |  |
| 6 | mno | P01-B02 |  |  |  |
| 7 | pqr | P01-B03 |  |  |  |
| 8 | stu | P01-B03 |  |  |  |
| 9 | vwx | P01-B04 |  |  |  |
| 10 | yz | P01-B05 |  |  |  |
| 11 | 123 | P02-B01 |  |  |  |
| 12 | 456 | P02-B02 |  |  |  |
| 12 | 789 | P02-B02 |  |  |  |

So, based on the above example, the above pallet (P01) has 5 unique boxes (B01-B05) and pallet (P02) has 2 unique boxes (B01-B02). What kind of formula should I use to achieve the result of 5 for P01 and 2 for P02 in column E? I was thinking of using COUNTIF but it doesn't seem to be applicable here. Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use the following formulas.

I added some helper columns to achieve the result.

[image]

`=UNIQUE(tblData[Pallet-box ID])` retrieves the unique Pallet boxes (column E)

Based on that `=UNIQUE(LEFT(UNIQUE(tblData[Pallet-box ID]),3))` retrieves the unique pallet no. (column G)

And now we can count the pallet no within the pallet boxes: `=COUNTIF(E4#,G4# & "*")` (column H)

Comment: Thank you! Using UNIQUE worked for me but it was your use of the wildcard "*" that was the major thing I learnt. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a specialist myself, but I have just created following example:

```
    A  B  C  D  E
 7              a
 8              a
 9              a
10              b
11              b
```

In a cell, I created the formula `=UNIQUE(E7:E11)` and next to it the formula `=COUNTIF(E7:E11,UNIQUE(E7:E11))`, these are the results:

```
a    3
b    2
```

So, combining `COUNTIF()` and `UNIQUE()` basic Excel functions might help you.

**Edit**: you might use a helper column, based on `=LEFT(B1,LEN(A1))`: I had put `P01` in cell "A1" and `P02-B01` in cell "B1" and the result was `P02`, the left side of `P02-B01`, based on the length of `P01`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using either **Excel 2021 or O365**, then you may try in this way as well,

**Unique Pallet No.**

• Formula used in cell **D3**

```
=UNIQUE(LEFT(Pallet_box_ID,3))
```

**No. Of Boxes**

• Formula used in cell **E3**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(UNIQUE(Pallet_box_ID),3)=D3))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Where **Pallet_box_ID** refers to the range

```
=$B$3:$B$14
```

Created using defined name manager --> select the range from **B2:B14** & Press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F3` --> Check **Top Row** from **Create Names From Selection Dialog Box** and Press Ok, now you can refer the **Name Box** showing the range `B3:B14` as **Pallet_box_ID**

Also I will suggest you to use this way because it may happen the Pallet Box ID can be **PO10** or **PO100** then **LEFT(Pallet_box_ID,3)** shall not give you proper output as shown in image below

• Formula used in cell **D3**

```
=UNIQUE(LEFT(Pallet_box_ID,FIND("-",Pallet_box_ID)-1))
```

• Formula used in cell **E3**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(UNIQUE(Pallet_box_ID),FIND("-",UNIQUE(Pallet_box_ID))-1)=D3))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the detailed formulas. I will take a look and try to understand as i've not used SUMPRODUCT nor FIND before. Thanks again!